# How can I split a text in 2 color vertically?

Tags: css, typography

I want a word in my div to be split in 2 colors vertically using pure CSS, any idea how I can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly use CSS3 gradient and clip properties .. I am aware of webkits which I used for, but not sure about other browsers, if you want you can try this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5rJ8R/) (Please view it on chrome)

```
div {
  font: 40px Arial;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0d2172 0%,#0d2172 50%,#ff2828 50%,#ff0000 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

> Note: As a web developer am not using any latest browsers, if you know
>   any proprietary property which works the same please feel free to edit
>   my answer

Comment: @CreepyFrog Well not sure but if you want to make it like that, better use an image instead of using CSS3 way, till all browsers support CSS3 properties extensively